# Android Studio Zxing Scanner, how to redirect to web page if result from QR code is URL?

Tags: javascript, android, android-studio, qr-code

this is my Code
I'm looking for some help on my android app that is using the ZXing scanner. I would like it to redirect to a website if the result is URL. Thanks in advance.

The following is my code:

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    button = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button);
    final Activity activity = this;
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(activity);
            integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.ALL_CODE_TYPES);
            integrator.setPrompt("Scan");
            integrator.setCameraId(0);
            integrator.setBeepEnabled(false);
            integrator.setBarcodeImageEnabled(false);
            integrator.initiateScan();
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(result != null) {
        if(result.getContents() == null) {
            Log.d("MainActivity", "Cancelled scan");
            Toast.makeText(this, "Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Log.d("MainActivity", "Scanned");
            Toast.makeText(this, "Scanned: " + result.getContents(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } else {
        // This is important, otherwise the result will not be passed to the fragment
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        public void handleResult(Result result) {
            if(Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(result.getText).matches()) {
                // Open URL
                Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(result.getText()));
                startActivity(browserIntent);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

**This is the condition to be checked:**

```
if(android.util.Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(result.getContents().trim()).matches() ||  result.getContents().trim().contains("www.")){

      // code to redirect to webview
      launchURL(result.getContents().trim())

}
```

**To redirect to webview:**

**1> USING CUSTOM TABS**

> Add to your gradle

```
implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.0.2'
```

> Call this function to redirect

```
void launchURL(String url){
       CustomTabsIntent.Builder builder = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder();
       CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent = builder.build();
       customTabsIntent.launchUrl(mContext, Uri.parse(url));
       builder.setToolbarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext,R.color.colorPrimary));
   }
```

**OR**

**2> USING INTENT**

```
if (!result.getContents().trim().contains("http")) {
      result.getContents().trim()= "http://" + url;
   }
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(result.getContents().trim()));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (result != null) {
            if (result.getContents() == null) {
                Log.d("MainActivity", "Cancelled scan");
                Toast.makeText(this, "Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Log.d("MainActivity", "Scanned");
                Toast.makeText(this, "Scanned: " + result.getContents(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            handleResult(result);
        }
    }

    public void handleResult(Result result) {
        if (Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(result.getText).matches()) {
            // Open URL
            Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(result.getText()));
            startActivity(browserIntent);
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Not Match", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```